# Amazon SES substitute values (PHP library)

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I would like to know if there is a way to substitute/replace values in the body of a message. Let's say I have something like this:

```
Hello %user_first %user_last, thanks for checking out our site. Blah, blah, blah...

unsubscribe 
<a href='mysite.com/unsubscribe?uid=%unsibscribe_id&token=%some_token'>
    HERE
</a>
<img src='mysite.com/images/user-opened-email.gif?sid=%some_id'>
```

where %user_first, %user_last, %unsibscribe_id, %some_token, and %some_id are user specific values and cannot be the same from one email to the other.

Ideally this would happen in just one API call rather than doing a srt_replace and calling the API multiple times.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like that built into the Amazon SES service.

In PHP, this would be pretty easy to do with some basic templating.

```
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    $template = <<<TEMPLATE
Hello ${user_first} ${user_last}, thanks for checking out our site. Blah, blah, blah...

unsubscribe 
<a href='mysite.com/unsubscribe?uid=${unsubscribe_id}&token=${some_token}'>
    HERE
</a>
<img src='mysite.com/images/user-opened-email.gif?sid=${some_id}'>
TEMPLATE;

    // (code to send email...)
}
```

As for this:

> Ideally this would happen in just one API call rather than doing a srt_replace [sic] and calling the API multiple times.

I'm not quite sure what you mean. Each call to the `SendEmail` operation sends a single email, so you'd need to make one API call per email anyway.

Were you expecting something different?

Comment: Thank you for your answer I think it addresses my question. Sorry if it was not all that clear; The reason why I ask is because I think this is possible with the SendGrid API If you look at their library, they have a method to do substitutions https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#using-substitutions. If I'm not wrong I can add as many substitutions as I want and then just make one API call which will send multiple custom emails on their end (see an example http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/smtp-api/php-example/)

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not sure how SendGrid works behind the scenes, but somebody, somewhere, has to send multiple emails. They might do it on the SendGrid side. Amazon SES requires users to manage sending emails themselves.